# Requesting to webapi is error from swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to download all products from web api.I am using other api, they work good. But when I am trying download products list it is not work. I check it in browser, in browser it is requesting but when I am trying requesting from Xcode(Swift) it is not working. I used all versions to requesting: Alamofire, tryed to using `NSURLSession` and `NSURLConnection`, but all they are not working. How i can try to do this?
This my not working request:

```
func getTovar(){
    data.removeAll()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://admin.unimax.kz/api/Default1/Gettovar")
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            if let value = response.result.value {
                // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                let product = JSON(value)
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in product {
                    let img:NSData

                    if let src=subJson["sphoto"].string{

                        if src.containsString("jpg"){
                            let range = src.startIndex.advancedBy(2)..<src.endIndex
                            let substring = src[range]
                            var urlString = "http://admin.unimax.kz/\(substring)"
                            urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
                            img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)!

                        }
                        else{
                            img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                    }

                    //Do something you want
                    let p=Product(id:subJson["id"].int!,title: subJson["name"].string!, img: UIImage(data: img), price: subJson["price"].int!,desc:subJson["description"].string!)
                    self.data.append(p)
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using ATS (App transport security) for working in iOS 9.x.x? If not then first add ATS in your plist because you are using HTTP not HTTPS.

Comment: this one  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
    </dict>

Comment: Yes...great. go ahead

Comment: yes i do this stil not working

Comment: it isnt work about two weeks before it works goog maybe i need to do some configuration

Comment: Is `response.result.value` or `response.result.error` `nil`? If not what's its value?

Comment: no the erro is here: let p=Product(id:subJson["id"].int!,title: subJson["name"].string!, img: UIImage(data: img), price: subJson["price"].int!,desc:subJson["description"].string!)

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: thanks everyone for help! i solved my problem